# Can I iterate through an object type document field when querying a collection in cloud firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection "foo". Each document in the collection has a property/field "bar" that is an array of objects like so:

```
foo = [{
    bar: [{
        id: "random_string",
        "status": "string"
    }, {
        id: "random_string",
        "status": "string2"
    }]
}, {
    bar: [{
        id: "random_string",
        "status": "string"
    }, {
        id: "random_string",
        "status": "string2"
    }]
}]
```

What I want to achieve is I want to be able to query the db so that I can get two different collections, one with all the documents in the "foo" collection that have "string" as a value of at least one of the objects in the "bar" array, and another collection for all the documents that have "string2" as a value of at least one of the objects in the "bar" array.

Is that even possible? I'm struggling quite a lot to this one, so any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm also happy to change the db schema if needed, totally open to suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with a single query because Firestore currently doesn't support logical OR conditions.  In other words, you can't have a query that gives you all the documents where any one of a set of conditions is true.

Also, you need to be able to call out a particular field in a document in order to perform a query against it.  Without a specific field to use, the query can't use an index to speed things up, and the query would never scale at the magnitude offered by Firestore.